# Use 9093 as loadbalancer port strimzi kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

Is it possible to use 9093 as listener port for type loadbalncer or will it only work with 9094 for strimzi kafka ?

Thanks,
sgv

Comment: Can you share your strimzi deployment configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Strimzi version you use. The newer versions allow you to configure the listener types and ports more freely and you can have something like this without any problems:

```yaml
    # ...
    listeners:
      - name: external
        port: 9093
        type: loadbalancer
        tls: true
    # ...
```

The older versions do not support this and you can use only port 9094.

I believe the new format which allows it was introduced in Strimzi 0.20 or something like that? For sure long time ago.